# Print an entry in a list and the amount of times it is in the list

Tags: python-3.x

In Python I am trying to print an entry from a list and then print the amount of times that entry is in the list. For example a user is prompted to type a department code and they enter 8 then they enter 8 again then they enter 10 so the output would be:
Department Code: 8 Count: 2
Department Code: 10 Count: 1

Comment: Please reformat your question and also show the code that you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `Counter` class from the `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4]

c = Counter(a)
print(c) # returns Counter({4: 4, 3: 3, 5: 3, 1: 2, 6: 2, 2: 1})
print(c[4]) #returns 4
print(c[10]) # return 0
```

using c[keyname] you will get the amount of times the keyname is in the list. Initialize the Counter object by passing your list as argument to it.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter